# Making REST calls from Drupal 7 to external API

Tags: api, drupal, webforms

We have an aging D7 site that uses the Webform module to send emails to our organization's ServiceNow platform.  The SN team wants to require the use of the SN API to process the webform submissions.

Is this even possible with D7?  Webform only seems to sent emails via smtp, and the FAPI appears to only work on incoming/internal REST calls.

To be clear, we need to send REST calls **from** D

We're at least a year out from upgrading out of D7, so I have to work within its ecosphere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a straight way of doing it, but here it is how I'd do it:

Are you familiar with Drupal hooks? That's the path I'd follow.

The Webform module has some hooks, I'd try with these 2:

- **hook_webform_submission_create_alter**
- **hook_webform_submission_presave**

Depending on your needs. Explore **webform.api.php**, inside the module's folder to see more details.

**A simple and generic example:**

Create a new module, let's say `webform_mailing`, then create a function that hooks into the Webform module, like this:

```
<?php

function webform_mailing_webform_submission_create_alter(&$submission, &$node, &$account, &$form_state) {
    // Do your API calls here
}
```

Your function will run when a Webform submission happens. You can then use the parameters, like the `$submission` to get the values, call your API and you're done!

**Note:** Be careful not modifying the `$submission`, as you see this value is passed by reference, so if you change it you can mess with your form submission data.

I hope this is helpful